# Get records which don't have relation with specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have models named **Order** and **Printer**.

An order can be printed by multiple printers but a specific printer can print it once.

I have another model **OrderPrinter** which keeps a record of which printers printed it.

So whenever a printer says PrinterA sends a request I have to find order which was not printed by that PrinterA yet and return it.

I am trying to achieve it like

```
Order.left_outer_joins(:order_printers)
.where("order_printers.printer_id IS NULL OR order_printers.printer_id != ?", printer.id)
.order(:id).distinct.limit(1)
```

**IS NULL** checks if no relation at all exist which is fine

**order_printers.printer_id != ?", printer.id** trying to find if it never got printed a PrinterA.

I know it has issue as if it's already got printed by PrinterA & printed before with some other printer say PrinterB than this check fails & it returns record, although it already printed by PrinterA.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a subquery:

```
Order.where.not(
   id: printer.orders
)
```

This will create the following query:

```
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" 
WHERE "orders"."id" 
NOT IN (
  SELECT "orders"."id" FROM "orders" 
  INNER JOIN "order_printers" 
  ON "orders"."id" = "order_printers"."order_id" 
  WHERE "order_printers"."printer_id" = ?
) LIMIT ?
```

This assumes that you have an indirect association setup in your model:

```
class Printer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_printers
  has_many :orders, through: :order_printers
end
```